# Texmaker does not edit pdf file

Tags: xetex, pdf, texmaker

I am new to LaTeX and using Texmaker. The changes I've made were successfully saved in a tex file. I see them in Texmaker, but the pdf didn't change. The problem is not in the pdf viewer because when I open the pdf by itself I cannot see any changes made. I didn't get involved in the work at start and a lot of work had already been done before me. There was no such problems before.

Comment: erh, we probably need a bit more information. Did you actually ask texmaker to compile and thus make a new PDF? Were there any errors during the compilation?

Comment: Do you happen to have the pdf file opened in another program, e.g. Adobe Acrobat? If so, it's not possible to change it while it's still opened.